# Java Regex Performance: Reluctant Quantifier or Character Class?

Tags: java, regex

Which of these is more performant, or (if equivalent) which one reads better?  I'm trying to match everything inside a pair of parentheses.

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\([^)]*\\)");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\(.*?\\)");
```

To me, the second reads better but uses the possibly confusing reluctant quantifier, and I'm unsure if that causes a performance loss.

**EDIT**

Don't miss the answer which shows this is even better:

```
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("\\([^)]*+\\)");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one has better performance compared to the `p2`, the non-greedy way, which will cause backtracking.

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\([^)]*\\)");
```

Look at [this article](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance).

Comment: @BartKiers in the linked article the author describes it as "with lazy quantification the engine backtracks forward after each character", which makes some sense to me.

Comment: @CoryKendall, ah, I didn't read the article. By the wording *"the non-greedy way, which will cause backtracking"* I thought he meant that the greedy way would *not* cause backtracking. I see what xdazz (and the author of the article) meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`\([^)]*\)` will be faster, albeit not noticeable if the input is small. A better gain is likely to occur when you make `[^)]*` possessive: `[^)]*+`. That way, the regex engine will not keep track of all the chars `[^)]*` matches in case it needs to backtrack (which is not going to happen in case of `[^)]*\)`). Making a pattern possessive causes the regex engine to *not* remember the chars this pattern has matched.

Again, this might not be noticeable, but if your input gets large(r), I'm pretty sure<sup>*</sup> the difference between `.*?` and `[^)]*` is less than that between `[^)]*` and `[^)]*+`.

<sup>*</sup> run some benchmarks to be sure!